# How to understand the recursive search in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Here is a section of Prolog code defining numeral in a recursive way:

```
numeral(0). 
numeral(succ(X))  :-  numeral(X).
```

When given query `numeral(X).` Prolog will return:

```
X  =  0  ; 

X  =  succ(0)  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(0))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(0)))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))))  ; 

X  =  succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))))) 
yes
```

Based on what I have learned, when doing the query, prolog will firstly make `X` into a variable like `(_G42)`, then it will search the facts and rules to find the match.

In this case, it will find `0` (fact) as a right match. Then it will also try to match the rule. That is considering `_G42` is not `0`, and `_G42` is the succ of another number. Thus, another variable is generated(like `_G44`), `_G44` will match `0` and will also go further like `_G42`. Since `_G44` matches `0`, then it will go backward to `_G42`, getting `_G42 = succ(_G44) = succ(0)`.

I am not sure if I am right about the understanding. I made a diagram to show my comprehension on this problem.
[image: diagram of numeral search]

If the analysis is correct, I still feel difficult to design the recursive function like this. Since I am new to Prolog, I want to know if this kind of definition always used in application (say building an expert system, verifying protocols) or it is just for beginners to better understanding the basic searching procedure? If it is often used, what is the key point to design this kind of recursive definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal opinion: *Especially* as a beginner, you have **zero** chance to"understand the recursive search in Prolog". Countless beginners are trying to understand Prolog in this way, and they *very consistently* fail.

The sad part is that this hits hardest workers the hardest: You always think you can somehow understand it, but in the end, *you cannot*, because there are too many ways to invoke even the simplest predicates, with uninstantiated and (partly) instantiated arguments, and even with aliased variables.

Your graph nicely illustrates that such a *procedural reading* gets *extremely unwieldy* very quickly for even the simplest conceivable recursive definitions.

A *much* more tractable approach for understanding the predicate is to read it *declaratively*:

1. `0` is a numeral
2. **If** `X` is a numeral (whatever `X` is!), **then** `succ(X)` of `X` is *also* a numeral.

Note that `:-` even means ←, i.e., an implication from right to left.

My recommendation is to focus on a clear *declarative* description of what *ought* to hold. To overcome the initial barriers with Prolog, you *must let go* the idea that you can trace the steps that the CPU performs in the extreme detail in which you are currently trying to follow it. Prolog is too high-level to be amenable to tracing in this low-level way. It is like trying to interpret between French and English by tracing only the neuronal activities of the speakers.

Write a clear definition and then **leave the search to Prolog**. There are many other and *working* ways to understand and break down declarative definitions without getting swamped in low-level details. See for example [program-slicing](/questions/tagged/program-slicing) and [failure-slicing](/questions/tagged/failure-slicing). They work as long as you stay in the so-called pure monotonic subset of Prolog. Focus on this area, and you will be able to make very fast progress.